# CSS: border color of input box has two colors?

Tags: html, css

Try the below code, the upper and left border color is darker than the lower and right border color. Why this is happening and how to fix this?

```
<html>
<input type="text">
</html>

<style>

input:focus{
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: none;

}

input{
    border-color:orange;
    box-shadow: none;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) values. Try finding one that works for you like `solid`. I'm guessing the `input` elements are setting it to `inset`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I used:

```
input {
  border: 0.5px solid orange;
}
```

I think defining the border in one line solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
input{
    border-color:orange;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <input type="text">
</html>
<style>
    input{
        border:1px solid orange;
    }
</style>
```

try this

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: by this user can also search this that why is this happening we can't explain such things here @JoshuaDwire

Comment: @JoshuaDwire this way user can learn more he will explore stuff related this that will be better for anyone