# input with 2 colors

Tags: html, css

I would like to put 2 colors (red and grey) on my input but it doesn't works. 
I looked here ==> [CSS: border color of input box has two colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386967/css-border-color-of-input-box-has-two-colors) but I don't understand...

Here is an idea of the result that I search.
[image]

However, I managed to get for now this only. 
Impossible to put two colors ? 
[image]

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div class="form_padding">
                        <label>Your Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" >
                    </div>
 </form>
```

CSS

```
input{
  height: 28px;
  width: 272px;
  border-bottom:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: #C22312; 
  border-radius:1px;

}
```

Do you have an idea ? Please... 
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: border-bottom-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input{
  height: 28px;
  width: 272px;
  border-width:1px 1px 2px 1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #C22312 #ccc; 
  border-radius:1px;

}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div class="form_padding">
                        <label>Your Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" >
                    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: thankkkkkssss you it works !! ;-)